# Cloudfront & Cloudflare 403 errors when loading assets from subdomain

Tags: dns, cdn, amazon-cloudfront, cloudflare

We have a Rails application running on heroku, whose assets we distribute via cloudfront as our first CDN.
The website can be accessed directly from its [cloudfront url](https://d1rm3nbxa795it.cloudfront.net).
The application pulls in external images from a wordpress instance running on a seperate server on the `blog` subdomain, which uses cloudflare as the DNS provider.
As long as the website is accessed from its cloudfront url of [`https://[redacted].cloudfront.net`](https://d1rm3nbxa795it.cloudfront.net), the external assets are loading fine.

[`https://[redacted].cloudfront.net/blog/1192`](https://d1rm3nbxa795it.cloudfront.net/blog/1192) embeds an image from our wordpress instance.

Here's the relevant request header:

```
GET /wp-content/uploads/2016/02/69blog-1-1024x604.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: blog.meinbge.de
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.54 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
If-None-Match: "1fd6f-52be33056b1af"
If-Modified-Since: Tue, 16 Feb 2016 13:34:12 GMT
```

and the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Date: Thu, 25 Feb 2016 13:33:11 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
ETag: "1fd6f-52be33056b1af"
```

As you can see, we get a `HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified` status on the resource.

Now, trying to request the same asset from the sites proper tld, which is also managed by cloudfront, we observe that a referer header is introduced into the request to the external resource:

```
GET /wp-content/uploads/2016/02/69blog-1-1024x604.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: blog.meinbge.de
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.54 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://heroku.mein-grundeinkommen.de/blog/1192
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

Since the injection of the request header of `Referer: http://heroku.mein-grundeinkommen.de/blog/1192` we get a `403` error when loading the external resource:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Thu, 25 Feb 2016 13:45:42 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Content-Length: 250
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

We supsect that the referer header is introduced by cloudflare, but are unsure on how to remove it.
**Question: How can we remove aforementioned request header from the HTTP request?**

Answer (score 0):

The Referer is standard practice for browsers to add. In your case it is most likely not being added because you are loading your assets from a non secure path. For security reasons Referer headers are not added in that case, since that would disclose in the clear what page the client was visiting securely was.

By any chance are you using SSL/TLS with CloudFlare? Since that may the trigger that causes Referer headers to be added.

Comment: Yes. We do indeed use ssl on cloudflare, and the ssl endpoint on heroku.

Comment: Your example URL d1rm3nbxa795it.cloudfront.net loads it's assets over HTTP, meaning Referer is not sent